# Estimating a limit of a sequence by several values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

Given first several values of a sequence, e.g.,

```
{0.291088365036517,0.34379330139259,0.370496101167372,0.383547058928976,0.389873503208829}
```

I'd like to  to find the limit of the sequence. In this case it should be something like 0.39... or 0.40... How to do it?

I seem to remember  that I saw once a command (or may be a package) that gives an estimate (assuming there is an asymptotic expansion?), but cannot find it.

Comment: Were you looking for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834)?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, exactly, thanks! I'll accept it as an answer.